# Light-cone coordinates

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, metric-tensor

The [light-cone coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates) are defined as

$$x^{\pm} ~=~\frac{x^0 \pm x^3}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Then in the light cone coordinates the position 4-vector becomes: $(x^+, x^-, x^1, x^2)$ .

Zwiebach, in his *A First Course in String Theory* [Second Edition,page-25], says that: 
There is no Lorentz transformation that takes the coordinates $(x^0, x^1 , x^2 , x^3)$ into coordinates $(x^+, x^-, x^1, x^2)$.

Why? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Lorentz transformations are by definition isometries of the Minkowski metric, but the metric is different in terms of light cone coordinates than the usual ones. It is not even diagonal!

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Can you please explain?

Comment: the transformation to light cone co-ordinates is a rotation (through 45 degrees) involving time, which thus leaves the form $(x^0)^2+(x^3)^2$ invariant, not $(x^0)^2-(x^3)^2$ so by definition the transformation cannot belong to the Lorentz group (spatial co-ordinate rotations of course do belong).

Answer (score 8):

If you compute $|(dx^+)^2 - (dx^-)^2|$, you will not find $ |(dx^0)^2 - (dx^3)^2|$. So, you cannot obtain $x^+,x^-$ (even with a different normalization) from  $x^0,x^3$ by a Lorentz transformation. None of the coordinates $x^+,x^-$ is time-like, or space-like, they are both light-like, and the metrics is $2 dx^+dx^-= (dx^0)^2 - (dx^3)^2$

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, the interval $$ds^2 = 2dx^{+}dx^{-} - dx_2^2 - dx_3^2 = 0$$ since the interval is always zero for light-like intervals, and the light-cone Minkowski flat space metric is such that $$\eta_{12} = \eta_{21} = -1,\,\ \eta_{33} = \eta_{44} = 1$$ and all other elements 0.